# Two string comparison

Tags: java, performance

I wrote a function that finds the difference between two strings. This only works given that the difference is continuous.

Beyond doubt this already exists, I am recreating this for educational purposes. I would like feedback about my performance and efficiency.

Examples of this method:

```
String difference = Difference("Hello", "Hello world!");
//difference would be " world!"

String difference = Difference("Removing text", "Removi");
//difference would be "ng text"

String difference = Difference("same size", "SAME size");
//difference would be "SAME"
```

---

```
public static String Difference(String string1, String string2)
{
    int size = string2.length() - string1.length();
    if(size < 0)
    {
        size *= -1;
        String swap = string1;
        string1 = string2;
        string2 = swap;
    }
    String difference = "";
    int start = DifferenceStartIndex(string1, string2);
    if(size > 0)
        for(int i = start; i < start + size; i++)
            difference += string2.charAt(i);
    else
    {
        if(start != -1)
        {
            int end = DifferenceEndIndex(string1, string2, start);
            for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
                difference += string2.charAt(i);
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
    return difference;
}

public static int DifferenceStartIndex(String string1, String string2)
{
    int maxSize = (string1.length() > string2.length()) ? string1.length() : string2.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
        if(((i < string1.length()) ? string1.charAt(i) : '\0') != ((i < string2.length()) ? string2.charAt(i) : '\0'))
            return i;
    return -1;
}

public static int DifferenceEndIndex(String string1, String string2, int start)
{
    int maxSize = (string1.length() > string2.length()) ? string1.length() : string2.length();
    int end = maxSize;
    for(int i = start; i < maxSize; ++i)
        if(string1.charAt(i) != string2.charAt(i))
            end = i + 1;
    return end;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I moved your description to the top because that way it shows up with a description on the front page. If a question just starts with a code block then instead of showing some of your description there's just `...` under your question title. Try to explain first than paste in the code in future.

Comment: A pair of testcases would make reviewing easier, it would be nice to add them.

Comment: @Caridorc I added examples? The function is working, I just want to improve on efficiency.

Comment: @OmarChehab, what happens if `string2` is somewhere in the middle of `string1`, is that situation expected? For example, "Removing stuff" and "moving".

Comment: @OmarChehab you are not forced to add them, but they would help reviewers

Comment: @Caridorc Sorry, I typo'd the question mark. I added examples, thank you for your advice!

Comment: @GentianKasa In that case it would not be following the rules of the method. I stated that the difference must be continuous.

Comment: @OmarChehab got it, I didn't quite understand what you exactly meant with "countinuous" there.

Comment: @GentianKasa Continuous in this context means without interruption.

Comment: When the difference is not at the end of the strings, such as in your third example, what is the rule for which difference is shown? i.e., what is the rule that makes the difference 'same' instead of 'SAME'?

Comment: @EricStein The second string's change will be shown. String1 is considered pre-change and string2 is considered post-change.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conventions

In java, methods begin with a lowercase letter.

### Design

Methods should be private unless they are required by clients. In this case, only the `difference()` method should be public.

### Implementation

There are a few things to look at here. First, your code is made much more complex by swapping around the two inputs based on size. It would be neater if you did the size comparison once, then called a helper method with parameters `shorterString` and `longerString`.

Your two size methods are clunky because they don't return early when they find a (mis)match, and because they run off of the longer string rather than the shorter string.

There may be a slight performance gain to be made *if* the two strings are frequently equal. In that case *only*, it *may* be faster to check if the two strings are `equals()` and `return -1` from `differenceStartIndex()` right away. In your particular case, I highly doubt this check would be anything more than clutter.

Applying these changes might make the code look something like:

```
public final class Difference {

    public static String difference(final String string1, final String string2) {
        if (string1.length() <= string2.length()) {
            return differenceHelper(string1, string2);
        }
        return differenceHelper(string2, string1);
    }

    private static String differenceHelper(final String shorterString, final String longerString) {
        final int start = differenceStartIndex(shorterString, longerString);
        if (start < 0) {
            return "";
        }
        final int end = differenceEndIndex(shorterString, longerString, start);
        return longerString.substring(start, end);
    }

    private static int differenceStartIndex(final String shorterString, final String longerString) {
        for (int i = 0; i < shorterString.length(); i++) {
            if (shorterString.charAt(i) != longerString.charAt(i)) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        if (shorterString.length() == longerString.length()) {
            return -1;
        }

        return shorterString.length();
    }

    private static int differenceEndIndex(final String shorterString, final String longerString, final int startIndex) {
        for (int i = startIndex; i < shorterString.length(); i++) {
            if (shorterString.charAt(i) == longerString.charAt(i)) {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        return longerString.length();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] argv) {
        System.out.println(Difference.difference("Hello", "Hello world!"));
        System.out.println(Difference.difference("Removing text", "Removi"));
        System.out.println(Difference.difference("same size", "SAME size"));

    }
}
```

Comment: @OmarChehab Note that this does *not* correctly handle the case I asked about above. It always uses the longer string's difference. It may be invalid or require tweaking to match that case. I'm not sure why difference("same", "samE") is "E", but difference("same2", "same") is "2", and I don't see a good way to make a general rule to fit that case. Hopefully this will give you a decent starting point.

Comment: I intend the return to be "E" in that case because it is the value that was modified.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
    String swap = string1;
    string1 = string2;
    string2 = swap;
```

should be moved to another method (in order to follow the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle).

In your methods, you access `string.length()` too many times (even in cycles). Given that the length doesn't change I'd suggest to memorize it in an `int` variable.

For readability's sake, you could transform `int maxSize = (string1.length() > string2.length()) ? string1.length() : string2.length();` into `int maxSize = Math.max(string1.length(), string2.length());`

That being said, if performance is key, I'd overload the methods with some other methods that work directly with `char[]` instead of `String` and contain all the logic and call those from the methods working with `String`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have added the changes. I do not understand why swap should have a method of itself. The single responsibility principle applies to classes, but not methods? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't change the original code you posted as it becomes unclear which version is to be reviewed.

Comment: @OmarChehab it was the Separation of Concerns principle. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, however, the latest should be the one to be reviewed.

Comment: It kinda goes against the [rules](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) of the site :-)

Comment: My bad, I am not familiar with them.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit to the question. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.